# Is destructor in PHP predictable?

Tags: php, destructor

Is a class destructor in PHP predictable? When is the destructor called?

Like in many languages, will a class destructor be called as soon as the object goes out of scope?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> PHP 5 introduces a destructor concept
>   similar to that of other
>   object-oriented languages, such as
>   C++. The destructor method will be
>   called as soon as all references to a
>   particular object are removed or when
>   the object is explicitly destroyed or
>   in any order in shutdown sequence.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: Indeed, as all references are gone, not necessarily if a variable goes out of scope.

Comment: this also includes when the script itself finishes executing.

Comment: But how can I call destructors in case of the script not finishes cleanly? In Windows, for an example, when killing a process, all ref-counted resources are automatically decremented on the same count they were incremented before the crash. I need to send a packet for session cleanup to another server in case of exception too.

Answer (score 4):

It's called when the first of these conditions are met:

- The reference count of the object goes to 0 (these usually happens when the object has no more variables that reference it -- they were unset or went out of scope --, but it can happen later, as an object may be referenced by something other than a variable -- in fact, the reference count is just a number and can be manipulated in an arbitrary way).
- When using PHP 5.3, when the garbage collector detects the positive reference count is due to circular references.
- Otherwise, when the script finishes cleanly.

In short, you should not rely on it always being called, because the script may not finish cleanly.